# Cloning git bundle over http(s)

Tags: git, git-bundle

Is it possible to clone git bundle over http?
When I try to do this i got:

```
$ git clone http://127.0.0.1:8888/repo.bundle
Cloning into 'repo.bundle'...
fatal: repository 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/repo.bundle/' not found
```

The reason to do that is to avoid compressing repository on the server (just serve file) and we are limited to `git clone` by user's application

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way to do what you ask. The original purpose of bundles is to compensate for cases where "online" access to a repo (e.g. an HTTP connection, among other things) isn't available; so I doubt that any thought would have been given to a use case like this.

I gather what you want is to prepare a subset of the repo that you anticipate needing to transfer, so that requests for that subset don't incur costs to either transfer additional data or separate what's needed from what's not.  In that case, you might consider preparing a shallow clone instead of a bundle.  Note that the history for each head to be fetched from a shallow clone must include at least one commit already in the repo doing the fetch.  So for example, if you have

```
x -- x -- ... huge history ... -- O -- x -- x <--(master)
                                   \
                                    A -- B -- C <--(some_branch)
```

and you're wanting to share `A` through `C` in this way, you would

```
git clone --depth=4 -b some_branch url/of/origin some_branch_repo
```

Because depth is 4, this will include `O`, `A`, `B`, and `C` -- meaning that a fetch of `some_branch` can receive `A` through `C`.

Comment: In my case, I do want to clone from a bundle accessible on a static site, through HTTPS, because I have no other way to expose my repository (work's policy...) and its full history, required by other tools downstream.